# Attach date to PDF generated with Sweave

Tags: r, sweave

I generate via Sweave a daily report. I would like to attach to the PDF´s name the current date in the format YYYYMMDD. I am using the following code to generate the file:

```
rnwfile <- system.file("Sweave", "Margin.Rnw", package = "utils")
Sweave(rnwfile)
tools::texi2pdf("Margin.tex")
```

Margin.Rnw is my master copy of the report I want to generate (mixing LaTeX with R code). The output I get is a the file *Margin.pdf*. I would like instead to have a file named *Margin_YYYYMMDD.pdf*.
I would appreciate if you have any advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `output` argument to `?RweaveLatex`.

This is untested but should (?) work:

```
rnwfile <- system.file("Sweave", "Margin.Rnw", package = "utils")
outfn <- paste0("Margin_",format(Sys.time(),"%Y%m%d"),".tex")
Sweave(rnwfile,output=outfn)
tools::texi2pdf(outfn)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks this is actually working fine. I have another question. Is it possible to specify also the directory where the pdf is to be generated. By default the pdf is in *R\R-2.15.1\library\utils\Sweave* generated. I tried to force it by changing the *wd* but it doesn´t find the *concordance.tex* file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: not sure; I'm a little surprised that it's looking for the concordance unless you have explicitly turned on `concordance=TRUE` in the chunks (I would turn this *off* to see if it helps).  The documentation for `?RweaveLatex` says that the output is (always) created in the current working directory.  Hard to say without more details/a reproducible example.