# Save a Sweave PDF output using custom file name

Tags: r, pdf, sweave

I have a sweave code that is producing a pdf. The code works fine. 
I run it from the command line using:"

```
R CMD Sweave --pdf filename.Rnw
```

The resulting pdf that is produced is save in the working directory as

> filename.pdf

Instead I would like 2 things:

1. Have the resulting output .pdf saved in another directory say wrk\random\dir
2. Change the name on a daily basis by adding the date at the end of it so I can maintain a history - such as filename.05032017.pdf

I tried using suggestions from here: [Attach date to PDF generated with Sweave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346979/attach-date-to-pdf-generated-with-sweave)
but that didn't work. Needless to say it could be because I am absolutely new to R/SWEAVE and suck?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that can be done on the command line, but you can do it if you run Sweave within R:

```
filename <- paste0("wrk/random/dir/filename", format(Sys.Date(), "%d%m%Y"), ".tex")
Sweave("filename.Rnw", output=filename)
tools::texi2pdf(filename)
```

You could put this in a *.R file and run it with `Rscript` if you don't want to start R.